# Why there is no Google+ history API in Google Apis console?

Tags: java, oauth, google-plus

There is no Google+ history API at [Google Apis Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus&pli=1#project:1041502198240%3aservices)
I"m trying to get the access of Google+ history API
But, i did not see it at the console page
can u help me with this..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

The Google+ History API is currently still in developer preview. In order to activate the API, you need to sign up at https://developers.google.com/+/history/preview/ which also has further information about the preview and the API.

Comment: 9 years past, how about now?

Comment: Now... the Google+ History API, along with Google+ itself, have been shut down since April 2019.

Comment: Oh, I remember that day,  like 2 years ago,  the whole service was gone.